# Get all print jobs from locale printer and cancel print job JAVA

Tags: java, printing

I would like to create a list in my web application (JSF) which includes all print jobs.
A status would be also very helpful (Status 1: currently print 2: waiting)

Another option should be: cancel a selected print job.

How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: this is only a list of the installed printers. I would like to have a list for the print jobs (currently and waiting)

Comment: Are you the one launching the printing tasks or do you also want to detect tasks launched by other sources ?

Comment: I would like to get only the print tasks from the locale machine

Comment: If you are the one launching the tasks, you can monitor their completion : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

Comment: which code do you mean?